# EOD parses content

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo a layout file in a textarea so that the layout can be edited from an online interface, but the problem is that, even in a heredoc in PHP it is still parsing the layout. This is the code I have to output the EOD;

```
echo (
<<<EOD
<div class="shadowbar">
        <form method="post" action="index.php?action=acp&mode=layout">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Advanced Layout Editor</legend>
        <div class="input-group">
        <textarea rows="8" placeholder="Layout File" name="layout" id="about" cols="100" value="$layoutFile"></textarea><br />
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <input class="Link LButton" type="submit" value="Submit Edits" name="submit" />
    </form>
    </div>
EOD
);
```

Originally I had the variable in between the opening and closing tags of the textarea, but I thought that if I put it in the value area it wouldn't give me the error. The problem is that the layout has closing textarea tags in the string which closes the textarea and then the browser parses everything past the first closing textarea.

I was under the impression, from the PHP documentation, that the heredoc would allow the form and echo the variable accordingly, so the question is, how would I make it so that it won't close the tag when it is echoed as the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<textarea>` don't have a `value` attribute. The proper syntax would be

```
echo <<<EOD
<textarea>$your_content_here</textarea>
EOD;
```

And note that `echo` is not a function call. While putting `(...)` are not an error, they are also totally unecessary.

Also, if you're dumping html into that textarea for editing, it WILL be parsed by the browser. e.g. if the html contains a form that itself has a `<textarea>...</textarea>`, your contents will actually terminate the textarea prematurely. Make sure you run your html through `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent that. i.e

```
$text_to_edit = '<textarea>foo</textarea> Please fill in the text box';

# Output your editor form
echo <<<EOD
<textarea>$text_to_edit</textarea>
EOD;
```

will generate this for HTML:

```
<textarea><textarea>foo</textarea>Please fill in the text box</textarea>
    a         b             c                                     d
```

You can't nest textareas, so tag B will be ignored, tag C (from your "text to edit") will terminate the A tag, and tag D will be a dangling/illegal extra closing tag. Now your editable text has leaked out of the form, and is no longer part of the text-to-edit.

Comment: The parenthesis are only because my IDE will not recognize Heredoc an Nowdoc without them, and it doesn't change how the script runs anyway. Also, I already tried that (i think I entioned that in the question) and it did not work.

Comment: as well, if you're posting html in there, it will be parsed by the browser. you'd have to run it through `htmlspecialchars()` to "un-html" it.

Comment: @MarcB If you edit your answer to include that, I can accept it, because that worked. Edit: I had completely forgotten that I could use that function, and when you mentioned it I was thinking that it absolutely removed the tags. I looked at the php documentation and found that's exactly what I needed. Thanks.